# Object of class App\Http\Controllers\ConfigClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I have 2 class:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ConfigClass  {
    const ERROR_STATUS = 'kod html [[X]] error';
}
```

Second class:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ConfigClass;

class StatusMessageClass
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = new ConfigClass();
    }

    public function createMessageWithStatus(string $messageType, string $description): array
    {
        $classValue = $this->config.'' . $messageType;
        $html = str_replace("[[X]]", $description, $classValue);
        $message = array(
            'messageType' => $messageType,
            'html' => $html,
            'description' => $description
        );
        return $message;
    }

}
```

And i use this code:

```
$val = $messageBox->createMessageWithStatus('ERROR_STATUS', "Błędny login lub hasło")
```

I have error in line (Object of class App\Http\Controllers\ConfigClass could not be converted to string)

$classValue = $this->config.'' . $messageType;

How can i repeir this?

I need this result: $classValue = $this->config::ERROR_STATUS;
But I need get this value "ERROR_STATUS" from $messageType in function

Comment: *"I have error in line"* -- what is the error?

Comment: Object of class App\Http\Controllers\ConfigClass could not be converted to string

Comment: I'm updated my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class constants are not supposed to be retrieved from an instance.

So you can get `ConfigClass::ERROR_STATUS` but not `$this->config::ERROR_STATUS`.

A workaround is to use `get_class()` to turn `$this->config` back into `ConfigClass`, then you can use the `constant()` function to retrieve whatever constant is in `$messageType`:

```
$classValue = constant(get_class($this->config) . '::' . $messageType);
```

If you know you will always get the constants from `ConfigClass`, you can simplify this using the class name (and double quotes for variable interpretation):

```
$classValue = constant("ConfigClass::$messageType");
// you may need the full namespaced class: \App\Html\Controllers\ConfigClass
```